# How to add a LinkedIn company page in Sprout Social?

Tags: linkedin

[Sprout](http://sproutsocial.com/features/social-media-publishing) allows users to manage Facebook pages, Twitter accounts, G+ accounts, and *personal* LinkedIn profiles, but as far as I can tell it's impossible to add LinkedIn company pages.

Is this true? Or am I just doing it all wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sprout Social currently only supports LinkedIn personal profiles, but working to integrate company pages as well. Our team knows it's something our customers need and hope to have news to share on that front soon.

(I’m the Social Marketing Manager at Sprout Social.)

Comment: Welcome on Web Applications Brit. Perhaps you can take some of your time to create an excerpt and a tag wiki too?